# Laravel Controller can't receive POST method. Is the "areas" reserved word by any chance?

Tags: php, html, laravel

[ErrorException Undefined index: available_areas] happens.
Somehow Other variables are ok.
I am not sure why available_areas isn't sent.
POST Data is sent to register function of RegistersUsers.

https://github.com/whitepotato/cleaning/blob/master/cleaning/resources/views/keeper_register.blade.php

https://github.com/whitepotato/cleaning/blob/master/cleaning/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/KeeperRegisterController.php

register.blade.php

```
    <div>
        <label for="areas">AVAILABLE AREAS</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="all_checked" > ALL<br/>
        <p>
            @foreach(config('ward') as $index => $name)
            <input type="checkbox"　name ="available_areas[]" value="{{ $index }}">{{$name}} 
            @endforeach
        </p>
    </div>
```

```
class StackRegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $areas = $data['available_areas'];
        //omit
    }
}
```

POST DATA SAMPLE

```
local.DEBUG: array (
  '_token' => '2F5dbNfyyjf9mFtKCSVgAt5K2xXzNyRja3VVZB4X',
  'name' => 'fgfgfgf',
  'available_profiles' => 
  array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '1',
  ),
  'profile' => '100',
  'email' => 'sffftfdfdone@gmfail.com',
  'adress' => '0',
  'station' => 'fdfdfd',
  'available_otto' => 
  array (
    0 => '3',
  ),
  'password' => '12345678',
  'password_confirmation' => '12345678',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use Request type hint.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $areas = $request->available_areas;
    //$areas = $request->input('available_areas'); //another way to get
}
```

To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class on your controller method. The incoming request instance will automatically be injected by the `service container:`